# AHK for creating folder + subfolders

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I need an AHK script which creates:

- a folder in the currently open folder in Windows Explorer (under Windows 7),
- whose name consists

  - the current date in the format (`yyyy-mm-dd`)
  - the text which is currently in the clipboard
- the newly created folder must contain 3 subfolders, named "1", "2", and "3"

I'd like to copy a few words (e.g. `Testing Testing Testing`) from another application, go to a location on my harddisk (using Windows Explorer), activate the hotkey, and AHK will create for me a folder named:

```
2012-06-04 Testing Testing Testing
```

with subfolders "1", "2", and "3".

Comment: What have you tried already? Where are you getting stuck during creation of the AHK script?  Or are you just asking us to write it for you?

Comment: i'm a AHK beginner and this is too complex for me

Answer (score 1):

#### The script

```
#c::
    WinGetClass, WinClass, A
    if (WinClass = "CabinetWClass")
    {
        FormatTime, CurrentDate,, yy-MM-dd
        CustomText = %Clipboard%
        Clipboard = 
        SendPlay, !d^c
        ClipWait, 1
        If ErrorLevel
        {
            MsgBox, Could not read directory name.
            return
        }
        CurrentDir = %Clipboard%
        Clipboard = %CustomText%
        NewDir = %CurrentDir%\%CurrentDate% %CustomText%
        Run, cmd /c (md "%NewDir%" || pause) && md "%NewDir%\1" && md "%NewDir%\2" && md "%NewDir%\3"
    }
    else
        SendPlay, #c
return
```

#### How it works

- `#c:: ... return` specifies a key combination (here: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and executes `...` when hit.
- `WinGetClass, WinClass, A` stores the currently active window's title in the variable `WinClass`.
- `if (WinClass = "CabinetWClass") { ... }` check if `WinClass` is `CabinetWClass` (Windows Explorer's class).

  If so:, `...` gets executed. Otherwise, `SendPlay, #c` emulates a normal <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> stroke.
- `FormatTime, CurrentDate,, yy-MM-dd` stores the current date (`YY-MM-DD`) in the variable `CurrentDate`.
- `Clipboard =` clears the clipboard, so we can check when something gets copied to it.
- `CustomText = %Clipboard%` copies the current clipboard content in the variable `CustomText`.
- `SendPlay, !d^c` selects the address bar and copies its content to the clipboard.
- `ClipWait, 1` waits for up to one second for the clipboard to contain any data.
- `If ErrorLevel { ... }` checks if the clipboard contains any data.

  If it doesn't, the script aborts.
- `CurrentDir = %Clipboard%` copies the current clipboard content in the variable `CurrentDir`.
- `Clipboard = %CustomText%` sets the clipboard back to its original value.
- `NewDir = %CurrentDir%\%CurrentDate% %CustomText%` specifies the new directory's name.
- `Run, cmd /c ...` executes the command `...` and then exits.

  - `(md "%NewDir%" || pause)` tries to create `%NewDir%`. On failure, it pauses, so you can see the error message.
  - `md "%NewDir%\1" && md "%NewDir%\2" && md "%NewDir%\3"` creates the 3 subdirectories.

Comment: thank you for your help but i cannot make it work. i paste the script in a .ahk file but what i see when i execute it is a quick flash of a command window and nothing happens

Comment: @quanto: I tested it, and it works on my machine. What's your OS's language? The key combination `[Ctrl] + A` (to select all text) may vary on non English versions.

Comment: If I execute the script once, the cmd window just flashes for a while and nothing happens. If I try again, then there's a message: A subdirectory or file blabla\2012-06-05 blabla already exists. Press any key to continue... Maybe the path is wrong. I use English in my OS. Ctrl+A works

Comment: Troubleshooting: Does the first `blabla` match the directory you were browsing when hitting the hotkey?  Do you have any programs monitoring the clipboard? What custom text did you copy to your clipboard?

Comment: The custom text in the clipboard is "blabla". The directory I'm browsing has a totally different name. I exited most of the background applications but i'm not sure if the others monitor the clipboard.

Comment: Hi Dennis, your script works just as I wanted except for the fact that it ALWAYS places the folder on the desktop - no matter which is my current folder. For example, when I copy the text "testing testing" in the clipboard and execute the script, it creates the folder "testing testing" on the desktop, which contains the folder "2012-06-11 testing testing" with its subfolders 1, 2 and 3. In fact, the "2012-06-11 testing testing" with its subfolders must be placed in the folder I've opened while executing the script (e.g. G:\Desktop\tasks\monthly\ or M:\testfolder\). Any ideas?

Comment: I tried using: CurrentDir = %CD% but it doesn't work

Comment: Based on my experience with another user, I've tweaked the script a little. If it still doesn't work, try replacing every `SendPlay` by `Send`.